# Send text from Qt textEdit control to QML TextInput control using Qt/QML

Tags: qml

I have created a UI in widget and added a edittext control and a pushButton control to it. In the QML file I have a TextInput control. I am able to display the Widget controls in the QML. Now I want to set the EditText control text in the QML to the text in the edittext control that is there inside the widget when the pushButton of the Widget is clicked. On button click I want to send the text from the editText to QML TextInput.

How is it possible.

I used the following to register and use the Widget in the QML.
main.cpp file --->

```
qmlRegisterType<WidgetContainer>("MyWidget", 1, 0, "MyWidget");
```

QML file contents:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import MyWidget 1.0
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "gray"
    TextInput {
        id: textInput1
        x: 10
        y: 10
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "black"
        cursorVisible: true
        text: widget.getText()
    }

    MyWidget {
        id: widget
        x:10;
        y:70
        width: 180;
        height: 150
        text: "Widget text"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you receive the click events that happen on the button? i.e. Does the button emit pressed or clicked signal? If you can receive this then it is possible to do what you are asking for. Otherwise , if you are using QGraphicsProxyWidget for displaying your Widget on QML then probably the events like touch will be consumed by the QGraphicsProxyWidget itself and may not be passed to your UI components. Check for these things and report back.

Comment: Yes, the button emits clicked signal and I have used QGraphicsProxyWidget for dislaying my widget. I have also set the properties to send the MyWidget text to the TextInputBut as you can see in the code posted, still it's not working. Please check the following code: **`MyWidget::MyWidget(QDeclarativeItem *parent) :
  QDeclarativeItem(parent)
{
  m_SampleWidget = new SampleWidget();
  m_SampleWidget->setGeometry(10,70,300,100);
  mProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);
  mProxy->setWidget(m_SampleWidget);
  mProxy->setParentItem(this);
  mProxy->setVisible(true);
  mProxy->show();
}`**

Comment: I dont see any code which gets the text from the MyWidget text edit and set it to textInput1. The textInput text will be set only at the time of creation, it will not be set as you change text in your MyWidget text box. You have to connect the onClicked signal to a function which sets the text data in textInput1.

Answer (score 1):

Class `WidgetContainer` should emit signal when button is clicked. Then you will be able to write the clicked handled which you need in QML.

By default button (or any other member of `WidgetContainer` class) is not available in QML code. So you can't use button's `clicked` signal in QML directly.
You need to declare e.g. `buttonClicked` signal in`WidgetContainer` class. Then you need to connect `WidgetContainer`'s `buttonClicked` signal to button's `clicked` signal.

Now you can use `buttonClicked` signal in QML:

```
TextInput {
    id: textInput1
    text: widget.getText()
}

MyWidget {
    id: widget
    text: "Widget text"
    onButtonClicked: textInput1.text = text
}
```